# Query keeps executing when click cancel it then says rows affected

Tags: sql-server

i need to make a system that calculates the salary of staff for a given type of work (see if statements) using procedures and cursors but when excuting the cursor it keeps on loading and when cancelled it updates the table and set all values to the same as the first if statement in the stored procedure

```
create procedure salaryproc @booking_type varchar(50), @staff_type varchar(50), @salary int = 0
as 
begin 

if(@booking_type='personal' and @staff_type='booking')
  begin 
    set @salary = 1500+2300
  end

if(@booking_type='personal' and @staff_type='catering')
 begin 
    set @salary = 1500+1900
  end

if(@booking_type='official' and @staff_type='booking')
  begin 
    set @salary = 1800+2300
  end

  if(@booking_type='official' and @staff_type='catering')
 begin 
    set @salary = 1800+1900
  end

update staff
  set salary=@salary

 end
```

---

```
declare @booking_type varchar(50)
declare @staff_type varchar(50)
declare @salary int

declare salary_cursor cursor

for select b.type, s.type, s.salary
 from booking as b, staff as s

 open salary_cursor
     fetch next from salary_cursor
     into @booking_type, @staff_type, @salary

     while(@@fetch_status=0)
              begin 

               exec salaryproc @booking_type , @staff_type, @salary

             end
close salary_cursor
```

Comment: First set "SET XACT_ABORT ON" on your store procedure to control failures and aborts, second try to do a cross join instead of your cursor, Cursors are only usable for very specific purposes and are known for being slow and for blocking transaction tables.

Comment: You have `update staff set salary=@salary` as one of the first things in this SP. Are you **really** wanting to change the value `salary` for **every** staff members at the beginning of your SP?

Comment: @Larnu yes i only need to update the salary column for each staff according to their type

Comment: But that isn't what that statement is doing. There's no `WHERE` there @Cat_img.jpeg. That statement will `UPDATE` **every single row** in the table `staff` with the value of `@salary`.

Comment: Using a cursor here is absolutely the wrong way to go about this. And very likely your join from booking to staff is going to result in additional processing you don't want or need because you have a cross join there. This RBAR (row by agonizing row) process can easily be rewritten into a single update statement.

Comment: but you update all staff whatever their type

Comment: @Larnu i need to check the type and its not working

Comment: how your tables `booking` and `staff` are related with each other?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin there are only 2types of booking `official` and `personal`, for staff there are `booking` and `catering`, i joined them so that i can compare and set the amount to be paid

Comment: You have an infinite loop in your cursor code - and that is why "it keeps loading" until you cancel the batch. You need to master basic tsql first - and that includes using best practices. You should also not be using old-style joins via the where clause. Lastly, a cursor is something that is rarely needed in well-written tsql; it is a topic that you should leave for a later date after you have a good understanding of basic tsql.

Comment: @SMor exactly but the lecturer want all of us to do our assignment using cursors and proc only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do your update with one statement

```
update staff
set    salary = 
         case when bookingType = 'personal' and staffType = 'booking' then 1500+2300
              when bookingType = 'personal' and staffType = 'catering' then 1500+1900
              when bookingType = 'official' and staffType = 'booking' then 1800+2300
              when bookingType = 'official' and staffType = 'catering' then 1800+1900
              else salary
         end
where  bookingType in ('personal', 'official')
and    stafftype in ('booking', 'catering')
```

Answer (score 2):

The update statement in salaryproc is updating every record in the staff table. Add a where statement to reduce it down to the records you want updated.

```
update staff
    set salary=@salary
where
    bookingType = @booking_type
    and staffType = @staff_type
```

The cursor and stored procedure can be simplified down to set based update statements. Set based operations are preferable to cursors.

```
-- set the salary for personal + booking
update staff
    set salary= 1500+2300
where
    bookingType = 'personal'
    and staffType = 'booking'

-- set the salary for personal + catering
update staff
    set salary= 1500+1900
where
    bookingType = 'personal'
    and staffType = 'catering'

-- set the salary for official + booking
update staff
    set salary= 1800+2300
where
    bookingType = 'official'
    and staffType = 'booking'

-- set the salary for official + catering
update staff
    set salary= 1800+1900
where
    bookingType = 'official'
    and staffType = 'catering'
```